# Question about generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear Algebra Done Right states:
Suppose $V$ is a complex vector space $T \in\mathcal{L}(V)$.Let $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{m}$ be distinct eigenvalues of $T$.Then

(1)$V=G(\lambda_{1},T) \oplus \dots \oplus G(\lambda_{m},T)$

(2)each $(T-\lambda_{j}I)|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}$ is nilpotent.

Where $G(\lambda_{j},T)$ is the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_{j}$.

My question is does each $(T-\lambda_{j}I)|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}$ is nilpotent mean that $(T-\lambda_{j}I)^{dimV}|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}=0$ or $(T-\lambda_{j}I)^{dimG(\lambda_{j},T)}|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}=0$?

I know that $(T-\lambda_{j}I)^{dimG(\lambda_{j},T)}|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}=0 \implies(T-\lambda_{j}I)^{dimV}|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}=0$?

but does this part of the text mean $(T-\lambda_{j}I)^{dimG(\lambda_{j},T)}|_{G(\lambda_{j},T)}=0$?

Comment: It means that there exists a number $n$ such that $(T-\lambda_jI)\vert_{G(\lambda_j,T)}^n=0$.

Consequently, the minimal polynomial of $(T-\lambda_jI)\vert_{G(\lambda_j,T)}$ is divided by $X^n$, and hence has the form $X^k$. It follows that $k\leq\dim G(\lambda_j,T)\leq\dim V$, $(T-\lambda_jI)\vert_{G(\lambda_j,T)}^{\dim G(\lambda_j,T)}=0$ and $(T-\lambda_jI)\vert_{G(\lambda_j,T)}^{\dim V}=0$. I'm not sure how to deduce the equalities you want from this though.

Comment: I was thinking that knowing which is which is crucial in understanding how block diagonal matrices are formed from their linear transformations.

Comment: Does it also follow that the scenario would happen:Say $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are a basis of generalized eigenvectors in $G(0,T)$.Suppose $v_1 \in \text{null} T|_{G(0,T)}$.Then would either $v_2,v_3$ have to be in $\text{null} T^2|_{G(0,T)}$ and would this make $v_3$ have to be in $\text{null}T^3|_{G(0,T)}$?

Comment: By the Jordan form, you have a basis $e_1,\dots,e_k$ such that $T(e_n)=T(e_{n+1})$ and $T(e_k)=0$. Using that, I think you might check if your statement is true or not.

Comment: It is true correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, an operator $T$ is nilpotent if there is some integer $n > 0$ such that $T^n = 0$.  If $T$ acts on a space $V$ of dimension $k$ and is nilpotent then $T^k = 0$.  This is because if $T$ is nilpotent then

$V \supsetneq T(V) \supsetneq T^2(V) \supsetneq \cdots \supsetneq T^k(V)$

so $\dim T^k(V) \leq \dim V - k$.

Therefore, in the situation of your question, both statements are true:  $(T - \lambda_j I)^{\dim G(\lambda_j,T)} = (T - \lambda_j I)^{\dim V} = 0$.

Comment: Does it also follow that the scenario would happen:Say $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are a basis of generalized eigenvectors in the three dimensional $G(0,T)$.Suppose $v_1 \in \text{null} T|_{G(0,T)}$.Then would either $v_2,v_3$ have to be in $\text{null} T^2|_{G(0,T)}$ and would this make $v_3$ have to be in $\text{null}T^3|_{G(0,T)}$?